# Running python file with arguments works in terminal, but I need to use it in a different script

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, command, atom-editor

Running the following works perfectly when I do it in my terminal

```
python3 number_detection.py --train_predict 'P' --file 'Images/2/_newsize_1.png'
```

However, I need to be able to perform this task in a different script. I'm looping through images and want to return what they're recognized as.

So running the above in the terminal works fine, but how do I translate that code to work in a different .py file?

Comment: would recommend going through modules in python.  https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html. Then you can organize your code and refactor the modules whenever needed. So you will import number_detection.py in your different.py file, and then call the function.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is a way to advise you without seeing your number_detection.py file, but it would definitely allow me to give you more concrete advice if you post that.

Right now I would say, most likely you can put everything in your number_detection.py file, and turn it into a number_detection.py function that takes in your arguments

```py
def number_detection(train_predict, file):
    #put your original code here
```

Then in your image processing file,

```py
from number_detection import number_detection
```

and now you can use that other function in your new file